# Flash is not working in Chrome (Crossover Linux is installed)

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, flash, google-chrome, crossover-office

I have google Chrome 8.0.552.237 on Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit and flash is not working, I have tried a variety of methods to install flash, including Firefox flash-aid and the flash-installer package and nothing is working for me. I have even uninstalled and reinstalled chrome to no avail.

I get "missing plugin" message where flash plugin should be in a website.

What am I missing?

I have a variety of plugins returned by jgbelacqua's command:

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/firefox/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/iceape/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/iceweasel/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/midbrowser/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/xulrunner/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/lib/xulrunner-addons/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so
/usr/share/ubufox/plugins/libflashplayer.so
/var/cache/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
```

I'm not sure which is necessary and which not.

I should note tho that my Chromium does have flash and it does work... just not chrome or firefox.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/2544/where-is-the-flash-in-chrome

Comment: Yes Jorge but no luck there either.

Comment: I removed the files on the list and uninstalled everything flash related from software center, then tried the sevenmachines repo 64bit and got same list back.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags`?

Comment: Cumulus007: sadly no as this question was answered > 1.5 years ago and I no longer have that computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok Crossover linux added a second flash plugin through wine for chromium / chrome, to turn off the second plugin do the following:

```
   1. load chrome
   2. hit the wrench button
   3. select preferences
   4. go to Under the Hood tab
   5. under Privacy section hit Content Settings button
   6. select Features -> Plug-ins
   7. push Disable individual plug-ins
   8. In the upper right hit the + next to Details
   9. Scroll down until you see Shockwave Flash
  10. disable all entries other than /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so 
     (or the specific flash version you installed).
```

Reference Source: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108086

A second option would be to uninstall flash from your crossover bottles. For me this fixed flash in Firefox as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the beta version (9.0). I'm using Kubuntu 10.10 64bits, and Flash works perfectly.

You can get this version from the the [chromium-daily PPA](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/beta):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chromium-daily/beta
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Note: if you've previously installed the chromium-browser-l10n package for a multi-language browser, you have to uninstall it. This package is not included with the beta package, so you're stuck with an English interface.

Answer (score 1):

It installs Flash for FF. Restart Chrome and it works....
I read about these kind of solutions before. When you cannot install in Chrome try installing in FF.....
With thanks to Wizard1000

Answer (score 1):

Purge (completely remove) and reinstall `flashplugin-nonfree` with `sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-nonfree` followed by `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-free` . This downloads a new version of Flash player complete with new updates, etc. automatically. No reboot needed.

Comment: helpful answer for the general problem "flash isn't working" but not for the specific case with crossover

Answer (score 0):

After fighting flash problems on a couple of different Ubuntu installs, I came across a pointer to a FireFox add-in called [Flash-Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flash-aid/).  It is specific to Ubuntu, and it works to try to find the best Flash plugin for your setup.  Even though I prefer to run Chrome instead of FireFox, this little tool was able to solve my problems.

Comment: if you will read the question, it notes that flash-aid did not help in my situation, although good to know in other situations I suppose.