# Flash appears to be missing or broken in all browsers

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit, flash

In Firefox and Chrome (both latest stable, Ubuntu 11.04), flash is unavailable. I've uninstalled and reinstalled `flashplugin-installer` several times. I've tried creating a plugins folder in `/opt/google/chrome` and symlinking `libflashplayer.so` and `npwrapper.libflashplayer.so` in that folder. Going to `about:plugins` in Chrome shows me that the flash plugin is indeed installed and enabled, but nevertheless neither Chrome nor Firefox actually handle the flash.

I've looked through [some](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21578/flash-is-not-working-in-chrome-crossover-linux-is-installed) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2544/where-is-the-flash-in-chrome) here and none of those solutions seemed to help. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm running 64bit.

Answer (score 3):

What version of Ubuntu are your running 32bit or 64bit? If you are running 64bit I may have a solution for you.

`sudo apt-get --purge remove flashplugin-installer

sudo apt-get --purge autoremove

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sevenmachines/flash

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install flashplugin64-installer`

Then close all browsers, then rerun. Gives you 64bit for your 64bit OS.

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+question/158539

Comment: Nope, no difference.

Comment: The installation instructions for 64-bit flash are outdated, please follow http://askubuntu.com/q/11/6969