# Adobe Flash Player is not working in Google Chrome

Tags: flash, google-chrome, chromium

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and current versions of Google Chrome and Chromium. But in both of them flash player is not working. I can watch youtube videos properly. In other sites; it says missing plugin. Also I have installed Adobe Flash Player from Ubuntu Software Centre. I have looked for solutions from internet. I found nothing.
One of my friends has just installed Ubuntu and he says i can't watch, too.
Is there a solution? Or it's because we use Ubuntu in Turkish? What should i do? It's becoming really annoying.

Comment: It's Flash, what did you expect?

Comment: See this [Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25947/how-can-i-fix-crashing-flash-on-chromium).

Comment: NO,it's not crashing. It's not working. Is there any alternative to Adobe flash that i can use in chrome? :/

Comment: Are you using the 64bit version of Ubuntu? Maybe @Jorge's answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2544/where-is-the-flash-in-chrome) will help you. (also, no there is no good alternative that you can use easily) - run the update manager as well, just to be safe.

Comment: Did you install the latest updates?  Early this week there were some problemes with the player (i had them to) - but after updating the system it was OK.   You can go to Adobe.com to, an install the player manually - like they explain how to do it.

Comment: No, it's 32bit. Everything in my system is up to date. I have enough tech knowledge actually, but i couldn't find anything wrong.

Comment: Chrome already comes with it's own build of flash, tried in other browsers¿

Comment: Nevermind- see my reply below.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Google Chrome (but not Chromium, the basis, and almost an exact replica of Chrome) comes with it's own Flash plugin. I don't know if that stops it from using other plugins, but im guessing so, unless you edit the plugin path.

Try Chromium, which is available through the repos and is almost identical to Chrome, and test to see if that works OK. If not, reinstall the flashplugin-installer package, to reinstall the plugin

Answer (score 0):

One fix that seemed to work for me is this. Go to the [Adobe Flash Download](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?no_redirect) page and download the appropriate one for your OS & version. That seemed to fix most of my issues and problems.

Answer (score 0):

See [YouTube Problems Mega Thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1799217).

If you are not affected by the problems described there or if the solutions doesn't work, then you could disable the plugin bundled with Chrome. You can do that by typing **about:plugins** in the address bar, then  clicking the Details. Additionally, you could try to use [Flash-Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/) on Firefox to install flash and fix some issues. As long as you disable the bundled plugin in Chrome it will pick up the one use by Firefox. Just make sure you disable the option to *Override GPU validation* in Flash-Aid Wizard, because YouTube currently has an issue with that.

Comment: Thank you all. I found the problem. It was not Flash player. It is Shockwave player. The problem has changed. :)

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2011/02/23/running-32-bit-flash-plugin-in-64-bit-chrome.aspx) has instructions for copying the flash plugin from firefox to chrome.